# Why can't the following query delete duplicate rows?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have learnt that in correlated query, the sub query executes once for each row of the main query.I tried the following query.

```
table1
------
col1     

Delete from table1 a where 1<(select count(b.num1) from table1 b where b.col1=a.col1);
```

MY UNDERSTANDING of the above query is:For each row the subquery finds the number of other row with the the same value as current row, and if there are more than 1 such rows, the main query deletes the CURRENT ROW. So in the process the duplicates are deleted, but actually all the row are getting deleted. Where am I going wrong.

Note:- Please dont give query that removes duplicates. Please just help me where am I wrong in my understanding.

Further more explanation of my understanding: Let there are three rows with the value 5. At the first row the subquery returns the count 3, so the first row is deleted. for the second row the subquery returns the count 2, so the second row is deleted.for the third row the subquery returns the count 1, so the third row is not deleted.

Comment: You miss very important point. `All-at-once` operation, not `row-by-row`. So when there are duplicate rows, all  are deleted. Anyway using `COUNT`, correlated subquery and comparing with 1 is not best way (performance). You should ask for better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have been right, if you'd use a cursor, or some kind of loop.

What you are thinking is: it will get to the first ID the is duplicated, delete it, and when it will get to the other one the condition will no longer be true. Thats not correct - When you delete with a where like this, it marks all those that need to be delete, and delete them all together, not one by one. So both ID's that are duplicated will be marked as supposed to be deleted.

If u'd use a cursor or a loop, then it would have been like what you planed.

You can see about removing duplicates in oracle [HERE](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_delete_duplicate_table_rows.htm)